# PHP ReadFile Insert a code in readfile

Tags: php, file-io, insert

I have a php readfile script, like this:

```
<?php
$contentFile = "http://google.com";
readfile( $contentFile );
?>`
```

I want to insert a code in a specific line in the output of the readfile.

Example:

```
<html>
{top_code}
{Code i want to insert here}
{bottom-code}
    </html>
```

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `readfile()` streams whatever you're reading out to the user's browser. You could use the output buffering mechanism to capture that data instead, but then you might as well just use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead and save yourself a few extra lines of code.

file_get_contents returns the requested file/url as a string. Then you use standard [string](http://php.net/substr_replace) or [DOM](http://php.net/dom) operations to manipulate that 'page'.

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job

```
$contentFile = "http://google.com";
    $html = file_get_contents($contentFile);
    $html = explode("\n",$html);
    $line = $line_number - 1;
    array_splice($html, $line, 0,"Burim Shala");    
    $html = implode("\n",$html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this, to be the solution to the problem of RSS feeds using PHP without MYSQL
Thanks to http://bavotasan.com/2010/display-rss-feed-with-php/

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://wordpress.org/news/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array (
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
);
array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
$link = $feed[$x]['link'];
$description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
$date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
```